# Is there any possibilities to detect language of input text using angula7/angular material?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

Is there any possibilities to detect the language of input text, for free,  using angular 7?

I tried using the Google API, but nothing worked to me.

For example if the user writes:

```
"bonjour" => alert("language frech")
```

or writes:

```
"hello" => alert("language english")
```

In my case the user writes in any language he wants.

Comment: It's an old problem, believed to be impossible to solve on single words. The problem is, what if the word is "ananas" ? It's the same word in almost every language (except English). For longer sentences you can try [guessLanguage.js](https://richtr.github.io/guessLanguage.js)

Comment: Browsers also have [built-in language detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/i18n/detectLanguage)

Comment: @Jeremy Thille , thank you, i tried guessLanguage.js , but as u said this for long sentences. i need somthing like google translate (detect language )